# How to describe an object in the camera reference frame?

Tags: camera, coordinates

I have an environment with a sphere, a camera and the sun. Both the camera and the sun track the sphere, such that they point always to the sphere.

All the coordinates are referred to the origin of the sphere. After all the object are place with respect to the sphere I need to obtain the coordinates of the sun with respect to the camera reference frame. This needs of course to take into account the rotation of the camera reference frame that changes every time the camera's position changes. I tried to look online but I didn't find anything.

How can I do this? Thank you so much

Comment: How do you intend to use the coordinates?  The answer would differ depending on the use.  For instance, if you need them in a material, you would use a Texture Coordinate Node and a SeparateXYZ node to get the relative position of each, but in a python script you would reference the transforms through each object's properties.

Comment: an example and/or some screenshots with annotations would help to make it clear what you want....because....i don't get it.